# Jquery find and each selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, each

I am new to jQuery so please help me with the output.
Below is the HTML code used for reference.

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="level1">
        <p>
            <span id="level1.1">
                <div id="level1.1.1"></div>
                <div id="level1.1.2"></div>
            </span>

            <span id="level1.2">
                <div id="level1.2.1"></div>
                <div id="level1.2.2"></div>
            </span>

            <div id="level1.3"></div>
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I used following as script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (){
        var div = $("#level1").find("div").each(function(){
            alert($(this).attr('id'));
        });
    });
</script>
```

The result was 5 alerts with id of each div

But when I used

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var div = $("#level1").find("span > div").each(function(){
            alert($(this).attr('id'));
        });
    });
</script>
```

There were only two alert for level 1.2.1 and 1.2.2
I was wondering why there was no alert for 1.1.1 and 1.1.2 as they also have span as their parents?

Thanks in advance.

If divs can't be child of

then why is

```
<p>
    <div id="level1">
        <span id="level1.1">
            <div id="level1.1.1"></div>
            <div id="level1.1.2"></div>
        </span>

        <span id="level1.2">
            <div id="level1.2.1"></div>
            <div id="level1.2.2"></div>
        </span>

        <div id="level1.3"></div>
    </div>
</p>
```

Working fine ??

Comment: `div` can't be a child of `span`

Comment: @ArunPJohny Whilst I'm inclined to agree with and add that probably a div cannot be a child of a `p` tag either, do you have any concrete reference for that?  Also why would the latter two be `alert`ed as they are also children of a span?

Comment: @RobSchmuecker have a look at the rendered html http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/0zrfmmcw/2/

Comment: Try seeing the HTML generated in browser using developer tools. It will be much clearer!!!

Comment: @RobSchmuecker I think you can have a look at the html4 dtd http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html#inline

Comment: Are there any other such rules???

Comment: @ArunPJohny thanks for the reference, I've been coding HTML so long that I never even think about things like that anymore as they come naturally but when thinking about an concrete reference for the rules I couldn't think of one!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of your incorrect HTML.

The browser is going to generate your html as followed.

```
<p>
    <span id="level1.1">
    </span>
</p>
<div id="level1.1.1"></div>
<div id="level1.1.2"></div>
```

Because a `div` can't be a child of a `p`

If you remove the first `<p>` in your code, you wil get an alert of the 4 levels sub levels.

Comment: Thanks I got your point.
When i used firebug to see the HTML, it was clear

Answer (score 0):

`div`s cannot be children of `p` in HTML

Change your HTML markup with the following:

```
<div id="level1">
    <span id="level1.1">
      <div id="level1.1.1"></div>
      <div id="level1.1.2"></div>
    </span>
    <span id="level1.2">
      <div id="level1.2.1"></div>
      <div id="level1.2.2"></div>
    </span>
    <div id="level1.3"></div>
</div>
```

and you should yield the expected results !

Comment: Agree.. divs cannot be children of p in HTML but then it is the case with the second span also, then why it is working there?

Answer (score 0):

Because your HTML structure is not correct this how your structure is populated :

[image: Populated structure]

Answer (score 0):

.find() method only travels a single level down the DOM tree.

[Here](http://api.jquery.com/find/) you can find it.

The .find() and .children() methods are similar, except that the .find() method only travels a single level down the DOM tree.